# symfony2 custom passwordEncoder with user data

Tags: php, security, symfony, passwords, encoder

I migrate an old system of Users with symfony 2.4,
i want to plenty use the FOSUserBundle and the encodePassword function to use some properties of a user (for example, its id) but i don't find a way to insert $myUserObject into this MyPasswordEncoder class.

```
namespace Tykayn\MeluzineBundle\Services;
class MyPasswordEncoder extends  \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder
```

{

```
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt, **$myUserObject** )
    {
        return sha1('blahblah' . $raw . 'blehbleh'. $salt. $myUserObject->id ) ;
    } 
public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        return $this->comparePasswords($encoded, $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found some nice way:

create a custom password encoder into my userbundle extending the FOSuserbundle.

```
namespace Sdz\UserBundle\Security\Encoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;

class CustomEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder {
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
// do doctrine stuff to get the user info
return $hashed;
    }
public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) {
  return $this->comparePasswords($encoded, $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt));
    }
}
```

register the encoder as a service of myuserbundle, inject it the doctrine service.

```
services:
sdz_user.custom_encoder:
    class: "Sdz\UserBundle\Security\Encoder\CustomEncoder"
    arguments: [ @Doctrine]
```

configure the global security.yml

```
security:


encoders:
    # encodeur de password selon l'ancienne façon
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
        id: sdz_user.custom_encoder
```